# Form submit not working in Javascript function after innerhtml update

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms

I have a Javascript function called from a OnClientClick which is changing a forms action. The reason for this is there are other buttons on the form but only one of them is required to do the postback. I would like the target of the postback to open in a new window whilst altering the content of the sender form using div.innerhtml="Some HTML Code HERE!"

I have managed to write a function that works in Chrome, IE and Opera but I cannot get it to work in Firefox. As soon as I add the code to change the content of the Div for some reason the Form.Submit does not appear to happen. The content of the div updates but the new window does not open. If I remove the innerHTML edit from the code below the submit works and new window or tab opens as required. This problem on appears to occur in Firefox.

This is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      /* Used to change form submission to another address , by dynamically setting a buttons OnClientClick property on server side */
      function SetFormAction() {
        var frm = document.getElementById("form1");
        var paybut = document.getElementById("altCtButton1");
        var canbut = document.getElementById("altCtButton2");
        var altdiv = document.getElementById("divAltContent");
        frm.action = "http://www.awebite.com";
        paybut.disabled = "disabled";
        canbut.disabled = "disabled";
        frm.target = "_blank";
        altdiv.innerHTML = "<br /><p>Process has been started, please complete in the new browser window and return to the jobs list when done!</p>" +
        "<p><a href='/mysite/apage.aspx' class='btnType2' >Jobs List</a></p><br />"; 
        frm.submit();
        return false;
      }
</script>
```

So the function above is called on a OnClick event in from a submit button within the browser. It changes the action of form1, disables the button that called it then for paranoia changes the content of the div that contained the button.

Any help with why this function does not work in Firefox would be appreciated.

So, the markup which calls this function is from a div which rendered from vb code behind but looks like this:

```
<!-- ShowAltContentMessage() Template ASPX Code Block - BEGIN -->
<div id="divAltContent" class="box">        
  <div class="content">
    <input type="hidden" name="altCtStateData" id="altCtStateData" />
       <span id="altCtHdrLabel"><P><B>Proceed to Payment Details Entry?</B></P></span>
       <span id="altCtBdyLabel"><P>It appears a process was previously initiated however it may have been cancelled, please ensure you are not making a duplicate process.</P></span>
       <span id="altCtFtrLabel"></span>
       <input type="submit" name="altCtButton1" value="Yes - Process Job" onclick="SetPaymentServiceAction();" id="altCtButton1" class="btnType2" />
       <input type="submit" name="altCtButton2" value="No - Abort" id="altCtButton2" class="btnType2" />
  </div>
</div>  
<!-- ShowAltContentMessage() Template ASPX Code Block - END -->
```

Whats interesting is if I remove the line of code:

```
altdiv.innerHTML = "<br /><p>Process has been started, please complete in the new browser window and return to the jobs list when done!</p>" +
    "<p><a href='/mysite/apage.aspx' class='btnType2' >Jobs List</a></p><br />";
```

From the Javascript function everything works in Firefox with the exception of the content updating. I.E the new window or tab opens with the new web address and the buttons get disabled.

As I mentioned this code works perfectly in Chrome, IE and Opera so appears to be a browser specific issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your markup?

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the HTML too.

Comment: Just a pointer (not sure). You have set `SetFormAction` as `onSubmit` handler. In it, you are updating the `action` and calling `form.submit()`. But will this not invoke `SetFormAction` again? Which will again start cycle.

Comment: I know it sounds crazy, but try changing `<br />` to just `<br>`.  It's a void element and the slash is not compatible with HTML5, so you might be accidentally activating Firefox quirks mode.